# Cell size in Grid (Nearest Neighbour) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, nearest-neighbor

I am using Grid (Nearest Neighbour) in QGIS to obtain raster layer from point shapefile.

However, on execution of the tool and obtaining the output, the default resolution of cell is 62 m. However, I want to change the resolution to 1 m x 1 m. How do I do that. ? I am unable to find any option for that.

Comment: Good answer, I would accept this answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why the QGIS processing algorithm doesn't allow you to specify output pixel size easily in the GUI, but you can pass a pixel size to the underlying `gdal_grid` call (requires gdal >= 3.2) by adding [`-tr xres yres`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#cmdoption-gdal_grid-tr) i.e. `-tr 1 1` to the "Additional command-line parameters [optional]" box:

[image]

For gdal < 3.2 you could calculate how many rows (`ymax - ymin`) and columns (`xmax - xmin`) required and adding [`-outsize columns rows`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#cmdoption-gdal_grid-outsize) to the "Additional command-line parameters [optional]" box:

[image]

Comment: Does resolution of raster needs to be necessarily more than the search radius?

Comment: That's [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Unknown option name '-tr'

Comment: requires gdal >= 3.2

Comment: With `-tr 1970 1970` I get an error saying `ERROR 5: Invalid txe or tye parameters detected. Please check your -txe or -tye argument.`

Comment: @GevaertJoep [ask here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)